# When is the equation $Ax = b$ solvable in the integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with integer entries, $b$ a column-vector with $m$ integer 
 entries.

Suppose the equation $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.

It is clear that the general solution of the equation $Ax = 0$ can be written as a 
 linear combination of vectors with integer values.

But what about a special solution of $Ax = b$ ?

> When does a vector $x$ with $n$ integer entries exist with $Ax = b$? In other words,
>    when is $Ax = b$ solveable in the integers ? If it is, how can I find the integer
>    solution ?

I tried to implement the function linsolve in PARI/GP. PARI/GP deliveres the
 kernel of A with integral entries. Using matsupplement, I can find a special
 solution, if no column-exchanges are required. But for the martrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 &3 \\ 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 &0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the column vector $\begin{pmatrix}8 \\ 1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ , the wrong
 solution $\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ is given instead of the correct $\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$. Is there a way to
 always find a correct special solution with PARI/GP, assuming the system is
 solveable ?

Comment: My try for the function linsolve in PARI/GP is : linsolve(a,b)={u=matrank(a);v=matrank(concat(a,b));h=(u==v);if(h==0,print("keine loesung"));if(h==1,k=matkerint(a);s=matsolve(matsupplement(a),b);print(k," ",s))}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the special case that your integer matrix $A$ is [total unimodular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity) it seems you can use the standard [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

See here: [Using total unimodularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Using_total_unimodularity).

Comment: It's a little stronger than that. The elements of $b$ must be integer-valued as well.

Comment: As far as I know, simplex only deals with positive integers.

Comment: @baudolino But that was the case, the only thing I saw not mentioned in the question is the extra condition to maximize for $c^\top x$ for some vector $c$. E.g. if one chooses $c_i = 1$, one sets the solver to go for the largest feasable $x$, so that condition should be no problem.

Comment: @Peter That does not matter because there are equivalence transformations for the problems and you can transform between problems with that condition (positive integer solution) or one where arbitrary integer solutions are allowed.

Comment: @mvw Oh, I missed the condition on $b$ in OP's post. The simplex algorithm can work for feasibility problems as well by simply setting the objective function to be a constant (e.g. $\max 1$ subject to $Ax=b$). In this case, instead of optimizing, it just becomes a (nuclear-powered) linear system solver.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) was introduced to solve this very problem. It transforms the system $Ax=b$ into another one $Hy=b$ where the columns of $H$ are in echelon form. It is easy to solve the latter system, and one just looks whether the solution $y$ has integral entries. In Pari/GP the function is `mathnf`.